# How to initialize array in Generics with mix data types

Tags: java, arrays, generics, arraylist

I am going through the Java Arrays and additionally, I am looking into generics. Below are the two methods of initializing an array

```
int[] data = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

// or

int[] data;
data = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

But when I am using generics, I have mixture of data types for example,

```
String[] outcome = {"0 wins", "Tie" , "X wins"};
```

Above array has a single data type of String. What if in an array I have something like below

```
outcome = {7, "Tie" , 9.0};
```

now I have a mixture of data types in an array. How I can write it or if it is possible to do with generics? Can I do it with ArrayList?

Thank you

Comment: Don't mix array and generics. The fact that arrays are covariant and retained, whereas generics are invariant and erased is bound to get you in trouble. --- Instead of mixing different types in an array, create a class that represents your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: In my opinion, arrays are not a good fit for the problem, you should use objects instead.

---

This is not a direct answer to your question, but an answer in the form of a redesign.

First of, let us tackle your statement about generics and arrays. Arrays are covariant and retained, while generics are invariant and erased.

- **Covariant** means that when `B extends A`, you can Write `A[] aArray = new B[someSize];`. **Invariant** means that this is not possible: `ArrayList<A> aList = new ArrayList<B>();` will lead to a compile time error.
- **Retained** means that the information about the type is retained at runtime: an array always "knows* what type its elements has. **Erased** means that the type information is gone after compilation. This is also called [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

The mixture of covaraint and retained vs. invariant and erased has good potential to get you into trouble. That is the reason why [`ArrayList` uses an `Object[]` instead of a `T[]` as its backing datastructure](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java).

---

Now to the actual question. As was already said by others, we could go down the road ande create an `Object[]`. I would strongly advice against this since we loose all type information. The only way to get back that information is a `instanceof` check, which makes your code rigid. Imagine you change the type of an entry. In this case, the `instanceof` will return `false`, possibly leading to unwanted behavior and (best case) some test turning red or (worst case) we may not notice it.

Now how to get around this? We create a class representing (what I infer are) match results:

```
public class MatchResult {
    private final int firstTeamScore;
    private final int secondTeamScore;

    public MatchResult(final int firstTeamScore, final int secondTeamScore) {
        this.firstTeamScore = firstTeamScore;
        this.secondTeamScore = secondTeamScore;
    }

    public int getFirstTeamScore() {
        return firstTeamScore;
    }

    public int getSecondTeamScore() {
        return secondTeamScore;
    }

    public String getResultForFirstTeam() {
        if (firstTeamScore > secondTeamScore) {
            return "Win"; // In an actual implementation, I would replace this with an enum
        } else if(firstTeamScore = secondTeamScore) {
            return "Tie";
        } else {
           return "Lose";
        }
    }
    // You can add a method public String getResultForSecondTeam(), I omitted it for brevity
}
```

What have we won? We have types. The scores are always `int`s, the results always `String`s. If we were, for example, change the type of the `getReultforFirstTeam()` from `String` to, e.g., an `Enum`, we would get compiler errors for all locations where the type does not match anymore. Thus, we hone the [fail-fast design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) and are forced to modify the code where necessary. And thus, we do not even have the chance to get the sneaky, unwanted behaviour we had before.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to correct this:

> But when I am using generics, I have mixture of data types

Generics require **homogeneous** data types.  For instance, a `List<Integer>` is a list that can only ever hold an `Integer`, and a `List<? extends Number>` can only ever hold `Number`s, which covers other number types like `Long`, `Short`, `Double`, etc...but are referred to by the *single* type `Number`.

Anyway, what you're looking for is a Bag - a collection which can hold any arbitrary object.  You can implement this with an `Object[]` or a `List<Object>`, and you're going to have to check the type of *each* element you pull out when you want to use it, since there's no way in Java to have a heterogeneous data type, which is what you're looking for.

Comment: If the OP is interested in a little redesign there is a very good description of a heterogeneous collection in Effective Java 2nd Edition.

Answer (score 1):

1 way to handle this is that you create an array of `Object`, that can accommodate all of data types

```
Object[] outcome = {7, "Tie" , 9.0};
```

And later you can access objects like:

```
if(outcome[0] instanceof Integer){
   Integer i = (Integer) outcome[0];
}
```

and vice versa..

Comment: So for every different data type, I have to write the above condition?

Comment: if you are sure about data type then you dont have to write these, but if you are not sure then you will have to

Comment: Yes. There's no other way if you are using the object type. If you want to put some bounds, use generics.

Answer (score 1):

```
outcome = {7, "Tie" , 9.0};
```

is simply not legal.

You can only use this syntax - an [array initializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6), where the element type is omitted after the equals - in a variable declaration, e.g.

```
Object[] outcome = {7, "Tie" , 9.0};
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, you could use an Object array. Alternatively, you can use a generic class. Here's an example:

```java
public class Queue<E> {

    private ArrayList<E> queue;

    /**Unparametrized constructor**/
    public Queue() {
        queue = new ArrayList<E>();
    }

    /**Enqueues an element into the queue.**/
    public void enqueue(E val) {
        queue.add(val);
    }

    /**Dequeues an element from the queue.**/
    public E dequeue() {
        E output = queue.get(0);
        queue.remove(0);
        return output;
    }

    /**Gets the current size of the queue.**/
    public int size() {
        return queue.size();
    }
}
```

[Read](http://code.iamkate.com/articles/java-generics-type-erasure/) up on generics and how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to create an array of objects, since all objects in java `extends Object`:

```
Object[] arr = new Object[3];
//to add objects to it:

arr[0]=new String("element at index 0");
arr[1]=new Integer(1);
arr[2]=new Character('2');
```

And to find if the object at index x is (for example) an `Integer` then your going to have to use a cast:

```
int x = (Integer)arr[x]; //x could be 0 or 1 or 2
```

Also you can do it with an `ArrayList`:

```
List<Object> listObjects = new ArrayList<Objects>();
```